# Idea about Wifi Mesh In High-Rise Building?

Tags: wifi, mesh-networks

I’ve been reading about wifi mesh and I’m thinking, would it work if we had one wifi mesh plugged into the modem and then had many nodes going around the high-rise buildings, perhaps 3 stories up and down?

Comment: What exactly is the question here, and how does it apply to IoT (and not just networking in general)?

Comment: @hardillb I’m just wondering if that would work, and if that’s the case, whether it’s more economical than each household / office having a modem each. Is this the wrong category for me to post this?

Comment: If it's a general networking question, probably... better on superuser maybe?  This stack is devoted especially the to internet of things.  See the [help centre](https://iot.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more details.

Comment: If this is a question which is particularly related to IoT, please [edit] to clarify that.  Thanks!

Comment: @anonymous2 checked superuser, don’t think it should be there